# What to do when pip dependency resolver wants to use conflicting django plotly dash versions of a application?

Tags: python, django, plotly, plotly-dash

So I'm trying to integrate plotly with my django app however I'm having an issue rendering a chart. I was using VSCode which did not pick up the dependency conflict.

However when i started to use Pycharm. It said my Dash was version 1.11 which satisfies the django-plotly-dash but did not satisfy the dash_bootstrap_components which required 2.0.0

I have now installed Dash version 1.10 which conflicts with both apps just to show the error message below:

## Relevant error code

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following de
pendency conflicts.
django-plotly-dash 1.6.6 requires dash<1.21.0,>=1.11, but you have dash 1.10.0 which is incompatible.
dash-bootstrap-components 1.0.3 requires dash>=2.0.0, but you have dash 1.10.0 which is incompatible.
```

Any help is appreciated

## Answer

As django-plotly-dash is on the latest version, i've decided to install dash 1.20 and downgrade by dash-bootstrap-components to 0.13.0 (https://github.com/facultyai/dash-bootstrap-components/releases?page=2)

This has worked like a charm.. weirdly - Pycharm has a reference error for the imports but visual studio code does not show any error and my program/script works perfectly. The pycharm import issue may be due to a setting in pycharm? idk

Comment: thanks, i did not know this! edit: i feel weird making my own answer as the solution hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As django-plotly-dash is on the latest version, i've decided to install dash 1.20 and downgrade by dash-bootstrap-components to 0.13.0 (https://github.com/facultyai/dash-bootstrap-components/releases?page=2)

This has worked like a charm.. weirdly - Pycharm has a reference error for the imports but visual studio code does not show any error and my program/script works perfectly. The pycharm import issue may be due to a setting in pycharm? idk

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to solve this issue is to install the compatible dash vision that is greater than 1.11 and less than 1.21.0.

Solution:

```
py -m pip install dash==1.20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution can certainly help when the solution is possible (when the dependencies overlap).

A best practice, however, is to let pip's resolver do its job. As the error suggests, it can't take into considerations packages "that are [already] installed." To avoid this problem, install all of your packages in one command.

e.g.

Instead of...

```bash
pip install packageA
pip install packageB
pip install packageC
```

do...

```bash
pip install packageA packageB packageC
```

Using the first method, when installing packageC, pip can't reconcile dependencies required by packageA or packageB. Since they are already installed, it would be unacceptable behavior to ***re-install*** dependencies and ***their*** dependencies.

Doing them all together, gives pip the freedom to install all packages and their transient dependencies in a compatible combination.

That's assuming there is a compatible combination... .

Answer (score -1):

Before you install your extension, just follow the prompts

pip install h5py
pip install typing-extensions
pip install wheel

and then install your extension